# Check if Dictionary has a Value in any of its Keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, contains

So, I have a Dictionary and I need to check if in any of its `Keys` is there a certain `Value` present. As value, I use this class:

```
class Symbols
{
    public bool OPC { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And, I am assigning the dictionary with the following key and values:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Symbols> SymbolDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Symbols>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Symbols symbol = new Symbols();

symbol.OPC = false;
symbol.Type = "Type";

SymbolDictionary.Add(Key,symbol);
```

If I check for `SymbolDictionary[Key].symbol.OPC` (or `.symbol.Type`) I get exactly the right values. But when I try to do this in a if, it never returns `true`:

```
if (SymbolDictionary.ContainsValue(symbol)) Console.WriteLine("Something");
```

As it never find a match of the values, even if I add the value and check it with the `if` statement right away. Any hints about how could I do that?

Comment: It's probably because it doesn't know how to compare your Symbols class. What you could try is use Contains() instead and write your own ContainsEqualityComparer implementation of IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided works fine.
What you're actually doing though, is probably slightly different from what you've posted.
You're probably creating a new `Symbols` object, correct? This would fail:

```
        Symbols symbol = new Symbols();
        symbol.OPC = false;
        symbol.Type = "Type";
        SymbolDictionary.Add("key", symbol);

        //create new instance
        symbol = new Symbols();
        symbol.OPC = false;
        symbol.Type = "Type";
        Debug.WriteLine(SymbolDictionary.ContainsValue(symbol));
```

You should implement the `IEqualityComparer<Symbols>` interface and its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

Now, the problem is, a dictionary stores your items in buckets depending on its hash code (provided by `GetHashCode`).
You'd have to make sure that two `Symbols` return the same hashcode.

Your calculation of a hash should NOT depend on `OPC` or `Type` properties though: the hashcode of an object *must* remain the same while it's being stored in a hash map (e.g. dictionary).
And because those two properties can change, so can a hashcode that depends on them. And that would break the usefulness of a dictionary.

Guidelines and rules for implementing GetHashCode: http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Comment: Thanks dcastro for this great explanation and for mentioning this link.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you haven't provided any comparison methods for your class.

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the
>   System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an
>   EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of
>   Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

Some further reading:

- [Dictionary.ContainsValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [EqualityComparer.Default Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Equality Comparisons (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting these readings. I'm going right to them!

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: your `Symbols` class must implement [`IEquatable<Symbols>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) in order for the comparison to work "as intended", or you must install a custom equality comparer [when constructing the dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx).

The [`ContainsValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah.aspx) method uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` as the method for comparing the specified value with the values in the dictionary for purposes of determining equality. If the class `T` does not implement `IEquatable<T>` then the default equality comparer uses reference equality; this means that this comparison won't work:

```
Symbols symbol1 = new Symbols();    
Symbols symbol2 = new Symbols();    
SymbolDictionary.Add("key", symbol1);
if (SymbolDictionary.ContainsValue(symbol2)) ... // false!
```

So first you must decide what "equal" means in the context of a symbol, and then implement the equality comparison accordingly. **Make sure to read and heed the remarks in the `IEquatable<T>` documentation when implementing!**

Comment: Thanks Jon, that helped to understand what is really happening.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx

This metod uses default equality comparer, so you have to implement IEquatable:

```
class Symbols : IEquatable<Symbols>
{
    public bool OPC { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Symbols other)
    {
    //here your comparision code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this topic one may ask if it is enough to just override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on the Symbol class ?

When you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you are changing the way the object will determine if it is equals to another. And a note, if you compare objects using `==` operator it will not have the same behavior as Equals unless you override the operator as well.

Doing that you changed the behavior for a single class, what if you need the same logic for other classes? If you need a "generic comparison". That is why you have `IEqualityComparer`.